# Server Side sorting in an ExtJS GridPanel

Tags: sorting, extjs, server-side, gridpanel

I have a paged GridPanel and don't know how to go about adding server side sorting.  Do I add a listener for the sortChange() event?  Do I override it? Or is there another event that I should work with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. In the definition for your store just set

```
remoteSort: true, // to enable sorting
sortInfo: { // the default sort
    field: 'someField',
    direction: 'ASC' | 'DESC'
}
```

And on the server side you will now be getting a sort and dir request parameters specifying the sort field and direction. When the columns are clicked the store will update sorted by the column and direction you pick.