# Changing store extraParams before grid sortchange event

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

## Requirement

Every time grid data is sorted - before the event is executed I want to change the store `extraParams` with the values of new sort properties. Like If I am sorting a column *Name* in *DESC* direction - before the event is **executed** I want to overwrite `extraParams` of store with `dataIndex` of *Name* column and direction property *DESC*.

My store also has `remoteSort` property set to `true`.

I am using ExtJS 4.2.

## Problem

I tried `sortchange` event listener on grid but it is executed after the data API is called and records are loaded. What I would like to have is something like *beforesortchange*.

This all with `remoteSort : true`.

Next problem is if i call `this.getStore().load();` from `sortchange` then my data api is called twice, which does not make sense.

## Code

Grid listener:

```
sortchange: function(ct, column, direction, eOpts) {
    this.getStore().getProxy().extraParams = {
        'sort'  : column.dataIndex,
        'dir'   : direction
    }
    //  load() will call the data api again once the data loading is over
    //this.getStore().load();
}
```

I tried following grid listeners also but either I dont get new grid sort parameters or they are not called at all:
`beforeload`, `beforesync`, `beforeprefetch`, `load`.

## References

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338407/custom-function-call-after-extjs-4-grid-sort/12338906#12338906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `beforeload` event to change the extraParam object before it is sent:

```
listeners: {
    beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts){
        if(store.sorters && store.sorters.getCount())
        {
            var sorter = store.sorters.getAt(0);
            store.getProxy().extraParams = {
                'sort'  : sorter.property,
                'dir'   : sorter.direction
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: right, it sends sort and pagination parameters to the server. but `sort` parameter is in a array format and not as per my need. i have access to apis which can not be modified and need parameters in different format (sort=column, dir=asc|desc).

Comment: thanks a lot, it really worked like a charm :) but with slight change, extraParams is property of proxy hence the line `store.extraParams` should be `store.proxy.extraParams`. have modified your code.

Comment: if there is a need not to send sort parameter you can easily set sortParam: undefined